# How can I more easily install a Nema 6-50 outlet?

Tags: electrical

I'm installing a NEMA 6-50 outlet in a garage for future potential car charging.  The wire is a #6 3-wire, red, black, and white.

I'm not used to this size wire, and it's very stiff and hard to fit into the box.  The box is a metal 4x4 inch box, but it still seems difficult to get the wire in the box once it's screwed into the outlet.  The wire extends maybe 3 or 4 inches into the box.

So my questions are:

Is my box big enough, or do I just need to cut the wires shorter?  Ideally I'd want a longer box to more easily accommodate these thick wires.  I'm guessing the box is large enough, since I can't seem to find anything bigger.  I'm more used to cutting the wires long enough that I can make them extend out the box a bit, and then push them out, but 6 gauge is so stiff, this is difficult.  I've not wanted to cut the wires too short for obvious reasons.

Can I pigtail the ground wire with a smaller wire, and connect that smaller wire to the outlet, or does the ground wire have to be 6 gauge?  This was one idea I had to make getting these wires to more easily fit the outlet, but I don't know if it's legal/safe.

Comment: What size *is* your box? Also note that the ground wire in a 6/3 NM-B is 10AWG, not 6AWG

Comment: How deep is said box? Also, I take it this is an existing (old) ungrounded cable from a main panel we're dealing with here?

Comment: Note that welders are quite weird as far as Code goes (they have a whole article in the NEC *dedicated* to them), so "incorrectly" may not have been so true, although your rearranging is called for.  However, is there a way to route a bare ground wire from the outlet to anywhere on the grounding system that's 10AWG or larger?

Comment: A real electrician can help better with the wire issue, though my experience with the 50A outlets in my garage has been that it's just a matter of a little finesse to coil the length of wire just right so the outlet goes back in the box nicely. But the reason I'm commenting is that you should seriously reconsider the 6-50, and instead wire a 14-50. The lack of a neutral on the 6-50 is, at the very least, less-than-ideal, and more practically is a potential electrical risk, and may limit your choice of EVSE (some won't work without the neutral).

Comment: @SteveSether: it depends on the appliance. Unfortunately, some need 120V but use the ground as neutral. That's bad. The bigger issue is compatibility though. There are EVSE that require the neutral (for 120V) and won't work with 6-50. If you know your EVSE doesn't need 120V, go right ahead with the 6-50.

Comment: @SteveSether: lots of clothes dryers do. I don't think you can buy them that way now, but they are still in service and up until relatively recently it was standard. I don't know what the EVSE market is like -- I settled on Clipper Creek a long time ago and have seen no reason to switch -- but frankly you're not paying attention to what I wrote. The safety issue is secondary. The forward compatibility is primary. Plenty of EVSE are not available with 6-50 plugs, whether they require 120V or not. If you don't care about that, no skin off my nose.

Comment: @PeterDuniho -- you're mixing up 6-50 and 10-50

Comment: @SteveSether -- I'm asking if you have a way to retrofit a grounding wire from the box in question back to some other part that's grounded via either a) metal conduit b) a 10AWG or larger ground wire (i.e. a >=30A grounded circuit) or c) the grounding electrode conductor/system for the house

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: _"you're mixing up 6-50 and 10-50"_ -- could be. Doesn't change my advice about EVSE in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that cable for a new outlet.  It needs to go to the scrapper.

You'll need to re-run it with proper wire or cable, such as 6/2 **w/ ground**.

Given your complaints about the stiffness of #6 wire, I'd suggest running some sort of conduit, such as "smurf tube", and run individual THHN wires in the conduit.  That would do a couple of things for you.   First, you'd be able to use #8 stranded wire for 50A, since THHN is allowed a higher operating temperature.  Second, you could defer the "neutral" question and simply add the neutral wire later if needed.

Comment: @SteveSether You can continue it in service to the receptacle it went to before, and you can even retrofit ground to that receptacle. You cannot extend a new receptacle to that, unless ground had previously been retrofitted.  You cannot re-mark any wire to be a ground, it must be natively green or bare.  These are Code requirements, added when enough accidents occur to warrant the rule. Not least how would the next guy know it's not a neutral?

Answer (score 0):

I think all irrelevant due to what I see as an illegal install from day one, but when replacing with legal cable the NEC requirement is minimum 6" of free conductor from where it emerges from sheath.

The NEC has box fill limits, 5 in³ for #6, 3 in³ for #10 (ground up to 60A), adding 2 wire count for each yoke used (or 4 wire count if device wider than 2"). So (3x5)+3+(2x5)= 28 in³ minimum box size required.

Adding splices rated for higher temperature wire is not going to make it easier.

I don't see how your wire was ever a legal install, and don't see any provision that code allows running a ground separate from inside a cable as a legal install. The code has  provision to add a ground when replacing an ungrounded receptacle with a grounded receptacle, but if you can't establish that this was a special 250.140 exception circuit that allowed grounding ranges and dryers via the white neutral conductor then you never had a legal install to begin with. You might get a local inspector to grant you latitude beyond code, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: See NEC 250.130(C) for the equipment grounding retrofit provisions

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I just think he would be on shakey ground applying 130(C) provisions to a circuit that was never approvable to begin with. "I'll run this any way I want, and if caught I'll just call it a retrofit"